# Writing to a text file using ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Im totally new to ASP so any help would be very grateful. I have a html page which has a form for users to leave their details and when they submit it goes to a text file fine but what I want is once they have submitted it I want to have an alert saying "comment saved" and to stay on the original page so they can submit another if they choose but when the user submits it goes to a blank page. 
My Form is

```
<form method="post" action="comments.asp">
<br><br>
Age <input type="text" name="age" />
Name<textarea rows="1" cols="70" <input type="text" name="name" /></textarea> 
<input type="submit" value="Send Comment">
</form>
```

my comments.asp file code is

```vb
<%
Dim age, name
age = Request.Form("age")
name = Request.Form("name")
dim fs,f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set f=fs.OpenTextFile("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Wiki\Comments.txt",8,true)
f.WriteLine(age & " " & date() & " " & name)
f.Close
set f=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

Comment: I am totally new and this was the only way I could get the results. Please can you suggest the best way to go so I can change the code to a more suitable format? Thanks

Comment: Of course it goes to a blank page, you are not outputting anything? Have you checked `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Wiki\Comments.txt` to see if it contains anything? If you want to output the results of your form use `Response.Write age & " " & date() & " " & name`.

Comment: If you want to use an AJAX approach then you need to submit your form client-side using something like `jQuery.post();`.

Comment: @New2Programming: writing to a text file from a web page will not work if more than one user uses the page at a time. You have to use a database in order to permit any real use of a web application. If you have found an example on the Internet of writing to a text file, then you have found a very old example, from the days when only very few users would use a site at one time. That's a long, long, time ago.

Comment: You have to  put your ASP code and html code in the same file.  surround your asp code with an IF statement to check if the form has been submitted. If true, then the ASP code will run, if false it will not run and the form will be displayed in either case.  Your form action will be the name of the file with both the asp code and html code.  This works because the ASP code will always run before the html code.  The alert window will be from clientside javascript and will be triggered by a value injected from ASP code if it runs.  If the value doesn't exist, the alert will not be triggered.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so look into IUSR having write permissions to the directory or file you are writing.  If you are trying to avoid using a database to write comments or logs, then a smart approach is to write to multiple files and then use something like FSO to read from multiple files.  The performance will not be as good as using a database, but writing files with FSO is good for logs and other one off file creation tasks.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and information on this I have decided to start fresh with .net and connect directly to a database and since doing so it has removed all the issues. Thanks again

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```html
namespace A6
{
    public partial class imanik : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class RedTabele {
            public string sifra { get; set; }
            public string ime { get; set; }
            public string prezime { get; set; }
            public string adresa { get; set; }
            public string mesto { get; set; }
            public string broj { get; set; }
            public string mail { get; set; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                // Lista za mesta
                List<string> mesta = new List<string>();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("imenik.txt")))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        /* line = Шифра корисника | Име | Презиме | Адреса | Место | Број телефона | e-mail  */
                        string[] podeljeno = line.Split('|');

                        string mesto = podeljeno[4];

                        mesto = mesto.Trim();

                        mesta.Add(mesto);



                    }
                }

                List<string> bezDuplikata = mesta.Distinct().ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < bezDuplikata.Count; i++)
                {
                    ListaMesto.Items.Add(bezDuplikata[i]);
                }
            }

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // sakri i ocisti table 
            Table1.Rows.Clear();
            Table1.Visible = false;

            // uzimanje podataka iz txtboxova
            string ime = txtIme.Text;
            string prezime = txtPrezime.Text;
            string adresa = txtAdresa.Text;
            string mesto = ListaMesto.Text;
            string br = txtTel.Text;

            // lista rezultata
            // Gore smo napravili klasu za ovo
            List<RedTabele> rezultati = new List<RedTabele>();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("imenik.txt")))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    /* line = Шифра корисника | Име | Презиме | Адреса | Место | Број телефона | e-mail  */
                    string[] podeljeno = line.Split('|');

                    string sifraTXT = podeljeno[0];
                    string imeTXT = podeljeno[1];
                    string prezimeTXT = podeljeno[2];
                    string adresaTXT = podeljeno[3];
                    string mestoTXT = podeljeno[4];
                    string brTXT = podeljeno[5];
                    string mailTXT = podeljeno[6];

                    sifraTXT = sifraTXT.Trim();
                    imeTXT = imeTXT.Trim();
                    prezimeTXT = prezimeTXT.Trim();
                    adresaTXT = adresaTXT.Trim();
                    mestoTXT = mestoTXT.Trim();
                    brTXT = brTXT.Trim();
                    mailTXT = mailTXT.Trim();


                    bool ImeOk = true;
                    bool PrezimeOk = true;
                    bool AdresaOk = true;
                    bool MestoOk = true;
                    bool BrOk = true;

                    if (ime != "") {
                        ImeOk = imeTXT.StartsWith(ime);
                    }

                    if (prezime != "")
                    {
                        PrezimeOk = prezimeTXT.StartsWith(prezime);
                    }

                    if (adresa != "")
                    {
                        AdresaOk = adresaTXT.StartsWith(adresa);
                    }

                    if (br != "")
                    {
                        BrOk = brTXT.StartsWith(br);
                    }

                    if (mesto != mestoTXT)
                        MestoOk = false;



                    if (ImeOk && PrezimeOk && AdresaOk && MestoOk && BrOk)
                    {
                        rezultati.Add(new RedTabele { 
                            sifra = sifraTXT,
                            ime = imeTXT,
                            prezime = prezimeTXT,
                            adresa = adresaTXT,
                            mesto = mestoTXT,
                            broj = brTXT,
                            mail = mailTXT
                        });
                    }


                }

                // Create Table
                TableRow naslovna = new TableRow();
                Table1.Rows.Add(naslovna);

                TableCell tdSifra = new TableCell();
                tdSifra.Text = "Sifra";

                TableCell tdIme = new TableCell();
                tdIme.Text = "Ime";

                TableCell tdPrezime = new TableCell();
                tdPrezime.Text = "Prezime";

                TableCell tdAdresa = new TableCell();
                tdAdresa.Text = "Adresa";

                TableCell tdMesto = new TableCell();
                tdMesto.Text = "Mesto";

                TableCell tdBroj = new TableCell();
                tdBroj.Text = "Broj";

                TableCell tdMail = new TableCell();
                tdMail.Text = "Mail";

                naslovna.Cells.Add(tdSifra);
                naslovna.Cells.Add(tdIme);
                naslovna.Cells.Add(tdPrezime);
                naslovna.Cells.Add(tdAdresa);
                naslovna.Cells.Add(tdMesto);
                naslovna.Cells.Add(tdBroj);
                naslovna.Cells.Add(tdMail);
            

               

                
                for (int i = 0; i < rezultati.Count; i++) {
                    TableRow red = new TableRow();

                    TableCell sifraKol = new TableCell();
                    TableCell imeKol = new TableCell();
                    TableCell prezimeKol = new TableCell();
                    TableCell adresaKol = new TableCell();
                    TableCell mestoKol = new TableCell();
                    TableCell brojKol = new TableCell();
                    TableCell mailKol = new TableCell();

                    sifraKol.Text = rezultati[i].sifra;
                    imeKol.Text = rezultati[i].ime;
                    prezimeKol.Text = rezultati[i].prezime;
                    adresaKol.Text = rezultati[i].adresa;
                    mestoKol.Text = rezultati[i].mesto;
                    brojKol.Text = rezultati[i].broj;
                    mailKol.Text = rezultati[i].mail;

                    red.Controls.Add(sifraKol);
                    red.Controls.Add(imeKol);
                    red.Controls.Add(prezimeKol);
                    red.Controls.Add(adresaKol);
                    red.Controls.Add(mestoKol);
                    red.Controls.Add(brojKol);
                    red.Controls.Add(mailKol);

                    Table1.Rows.Add(red);
                }
               

                Table1.Visible = true;



            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
// Za tekstualne fajlove
using System.IO;

namespace A6
{
    public partial class imanik : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class RedTabele
        {
            public string sifra { get; set; }

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {

                List<string> mesta = new List<string>();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("imenik.txt")))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        string[] podeljeno = line.Split('|');

                        string mesto = podeljeno[4];

                        mesto = mesto.Trim();

                        mesta.Add(mesto);



                    }
                }

                List<string> bezDuplikata = mesta.Distinct().ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < bezDuplikata.Count; i++)
                {
                    ListaMesto.Items.Add(bezDuplikata[i]);
                }
            }

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Table1.Rows.Clear();
            Table1.Visible = false;


            string ime = txtIme.Text;
            string prezime = txtPrezime.Text;
            string adresa = txtAdresa.Text;
            string mesto = ListaMesto.Text;
            string br = txtTel.Text;


            List<RedTabele> rezultati = new List<RedTabele>();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("imenik.txt")))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    string[] podeljeno = line.Split('|');

                    string sifraTXT = podeljeno[0];


                    sifraTXT = sifraTXT.Trim();



                    bool ImeOk = true;
                    bool PrezimeOk = true;
                    bool AdresaOk = true;
                    bool MestoOk = true;
                    bool BrOk = true;

                    if (ime != "")
                    {
                        ImeOk = imeTXT.StartsWith(ime);
                    }





                    if (ImeOk && PrezimeOk && AdresaOk && MestoOk && BrOk)
                    {
                        rezultati.Add(new RedTabele
                        {
                            sifra = sifraTXT,

                        });
                    }


                }

                // Create Table
                TableRow naslovna = new TableRow();
                Table1.Rows.Add(naslovna);

                TableCell tdSifra = new TableCell();
                tdSifra.Text = "Sifra";



                naslovna.Cells.Add(tdSifra);






                for (int i = 0; i < rezultati.Count; i++)
                {
                    TableRow red = new TableRow();

                    TableCell sifraKol = new TableCell();


                    sifraKol.Text = rezultati[i].sifra;


                    red.Controls.Add(sifraKol);


                    Table1.Rows.Add(red);
                }


                Table1.Visible = true;



            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ASP.NET and not ASP classic, as requested by the author 

Answer (score 4):

```
<%
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Open the file for writing
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(s_path & "/" & s_file_being_created, True)
f.Write(m)
f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you writing ASP with JScript instead of VBS, the code might look something like this:

```
var fileSystemObject = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var textStream = fileSystemObject.CreateTextFile(filePath, true, true);
textStream.Write(fileContent);
textStream.Close();
delete textStream;
delete fileSystemObject;
```

Documentation references:

- [`Scripting.FileSystemObject` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object)
- [`FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method)
- [`TextStream` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object)
- [`Write()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/write-method)
- [`Close()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/close-method-textstream-object)
- [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)